# router.url not working in production

Tags: angular, apache

I have a problem in production (server with apache) with the Router component (angular 4.4.6)
Here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        <ng-container *ngIf="router.url !== '/login'">
            <div class="col-12 d-none" id="loader">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <app-menu></app-menu>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="router.url === '/login'">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </ng-container>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    name = 'Angular';
    url: string;
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        public router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

The local version works perfectly but in production, both ng-container are shown. I put a console.log(this.router.url) in the OnInit and it shows "/".
But even if the value was "/", my test ***ngIf="router.url === '/login'** shouldn't be rendering this part and yet it does.

The url rewriting works perfectly well as I don't have a 404 when I type mydomain.com/login.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try to print out in the HTML itself {{router.url}} and check what actually the value is coming up there ? Or even better write something like this {{router.url === '/login'}} to check what the actual value is of router.url. Only after knowing why condition is failing we can decide it is a problem with the route or something else

Comment: this isn't possible. some of them absolutely false.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.
With this condition 
`<ng-container *ngIf="router.url !== '/login'">`
The container was displayed the small laps of time my url wasn't yet redirected to "/login" when the domain was entered.

The application crashed cause my  component was using localstorage that the browser didn't have at that time. The localstorage was only filled when login was ok.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your `url` detecting the following way:

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  router
  .events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
  .subscribe(
    changeEvent => {
      if (changeEvent["url"]) {
        this.url = changeEvent["url"];
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Based on the [router documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router), I think it is generally a better way to handle the current URL.

Check the specific [Router event](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) you need as well - I guessed NavigationStart is your best take.

Also, try to use two differend [named outlet](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/):

```
<router-outlet name="appoutlet">
...
<router-outlet name="loginoutlet">
```

and change the routes accordingly:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'loginoutlet' },
```

Comment: This is working in local but not on the server...still the same issue.

Comment: Only a wild guess, but Extended my answer, please see if that works.

Comment: I tried it and he don't find the routes anymore (even in local) with that modification.

Comment: . Also, with that solution (without the outlet named), the routers aren't re-tested when there's a redirection like this : 
    `{ path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
     }`

Comment: guess the problem is something else then, sorry.

Are you sure there is nothing fishy around your production environment?

Comment: no, not sure at all. First time I put an angular app in production. Myabe that could be related to apache ?

Comment: what happens, if you write a 
`<p> local url: {{url}} </p>` over both of your `<router-outlet>` What is displayed in dev, and in prod?

Comment: I replace my template by this : `template: \`{{router.url}}\`` and it displays correctly the url.

Comment: can you use the url fetch strategy I mentioned in the answer? router.url property changes quite a lot. 

One last guess: try to use a <div> instead of an ng-container. Other from that, I am out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out the popstateevent:

```
this.location.subscribe((popStateEvent: PopStateEvent) => {
  if (this.isPopStateEvent(popStateEvent) &&
    popStateEvent.url.startsWith('/login')) {
```

(location is of type Location:

```
import {Location, PopStateEvent} from '@angular/common';
```

)

Comment: I'm trying to test your answer but I don't understand the code you put here.
What's the this in this.isPopStateEvent refering to ?

Comment: Sry, I was using the popStateEvent for detecting a browser back button click. You can just `subscribe((event: any) => {...})` and debug which kind of event fires and what it contains...